# Filtering Jira export CSV by Component prefix

Tags: excel, excel-formula, jira

I'm working on feeding data from a Jira export CSV into a larger dashboard. In order to make this data useful, I need to be able to reorganize the default "Component/s" headers into Component specific headers.

For example, I have the following prefixed components "Color - Blue", "Color - Red", "Shape - Square", "Shape - Circle".

Jira exports existing "Component/s" columns for a given ticket (row) alphabetically. As such, I might have the following CSV if ticket Sample3 didn't have a Color component:

```
Ticket,Component/s,Component/s
Sample1,Color - Blue,Shape - Square
Sample2,Color - Red, Shape - Circle
Sample3,Shape - Square,
```

As you can see, filtering by the first "Component/s" column wouldn't only include Color data, it also includes a Shape. Similarly, filtering by the second "Component/s" column would miss Sample3's Shape data altogether.

What I would like to do is transform this raw data based on prefix to create a new sheet with this format:

```
Ticket,Color,Shape
Sample1,Color - Blue,Shape - Square
Sample2,Color - Red, Shape - Circle
Sample3,,Shape - Square
```

Is there a way to create new columns in Excel based on a prefix string? If it affects the approach, my actual data set includes up to 10 columns of "Component/s" columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered Power Query? A formula can do this, but if you want to process the data further, it can get messy and unstable. Power Query would shape the data into the desired form and that can be further processed in pivots, data models, etc. In PQ, I would Parse by comma, Unpivot, Parse by "-", Repivot.

Answer (score 0):

Use Power Query with script:

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\ ...your path... \jira output.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=1, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type",1),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Top Rows", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Column1.1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Value", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Trimmed Text", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(" - ", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Value.1", type text}, {"Value.2", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column1.1", "Ticket"}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Renamed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Renamed Columns"[Value.1]), "Value.1", "Value.2")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

where you need to replace `C:\ ...your path... \jira output.csv` with your actual path and filename.

For example, if given this as the CSV input:

| Ticket,Component/s,Component/s |
| --- |
| Sample1,Color - Blue,Shape - Square |
| Sample2,Color - Red, Shape - Circle |
| Sample3,Shape - Square |
| Sample4,Color - Cyan |

it will create a table in Excel with this as the output:

| Ticket | Color | Shape |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sample1 | Blue | Square |
| Sample2 | Red | Circle |
| Sample3 |  | Square |
| Sample4 | Cyan |  |